# DotNetBrowser - Supported OS

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I have read the system requirements of DotNetBrowser. But I cannot understand what is the reason for using the minimal version of .net 4.0 and at the same time the inability to run the browser in Windows Server 2008 sp2 (x86) or Vista which support .net 4.5? Or is there any trick to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the support of the operating systems you have listed was discontinued in Chromium 50. Therefore, there is no way to use the latest DotNetBrowser version in such environments.

Comment: I think it's not an answer. Could you explain how does EO.WebBrowser use Chromium 54 and it works in OS listed above? You can correct me, but it's all .NET wrappers over Chromium. Isn't it? And moreover, DotNetBrowser isn't free and, of course, not cheap. It is wrong to decide what OS the clients should use.